# Joining two tables by date MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM history JOIN value WHERE history.the_date >= value.the_date
```

is it possible to somehow to ask this question like, where history.the_date is bigger then or equal to biggest possible value of value.the_date?

```
HISTORY
the_date     amount
2014-02-27   200
2015-02-26   2000

VALUE
the_date    interest
2010-02-10  2
2015-01-01  3
```

I need to pair the correct interest with the amount!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `value.the_date` is the date since when the interest is valid. Interest 2 was valid from 2010-02-10 till 2014-12-31, because since 2015-01-01 the new interest 3 applies.

To get the current interest for a date you'd use a subquery where you select all interest records with a valid-from date up to then and only keep the latest:

```
select
  the_date,
  amount,
  (
    select v.interest
    from value v
    where v.the_date <= h.the_date
    order by v.the_date desc
    limit 1
  ) as interest
from history h;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Think about table and column names telling more of their content. A table named `value` is rather strange; shouldn't that be `interest_rates` or the like? And `the_date` doesn't say much; a better name would be `valid_from_date` for instance. And `history` also doesn't say much either. History of what? I'd expect some name like `purchases` or `sales` or something along those lines.

Comment: That's correct! Thanks for the tips, I'll think about them further on :)

Answer (score 0):

use join condition after `ON` not in where clause...

```
SELECT * FROM history JOIN (select max(value.the_date) as d from value) as x on history.the_date >= x.d
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I'm trying to pair the amount with the interest by the date. 200 should be paired with 2 and 2000 should be paired with 3.

Comment: why, by the first higher date in history?

Comment: cause the_date of value is when the interest was added!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want this:

```
select h.*
from history h
where h.the_date >= (select max(v.the_date) from value v);
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to understand now.